# Sending email with embedded image using SMTP

Tags: python, smtp, html-email, smtplib

I'm trying to send an email using the SMTP library with an embedded image in the body. The email gets sent, but the resulting image is a textbox saying 'This image cannot be displayed, it was possibly removed or renamed...' etc. I know there is nothing wrong with the image itself as I can open the image locally just fine. The path and image both are valid, so I don't understand why it cannot be displayed within the email.
I read somewhere that I may be because of the `Content-ID` being too short, but I have no idea how to find a solution for that.

This is the code I have for sending the email in the method `send_email()`

```
def send_email():
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = "Subject"
    msg['From'] = from_address
    msg['To'] = to_address

    text = MIMEText('<img src="cid:image1">', 'html')
    msg.attach(text)

    image = MIMEImage(open('pictures/download.png', 'rb').read())

    image.add_header('Content-ID', '<ímage1>')
    msg.attach(image)

    try:
        s = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp-mail.outlook.com', port=587)
        s.starttls()
        s.login(from_address, password)
        s.sendmail(from_address, to_address, msg.as_string())
        s.quit()
        print('Email sent!')

    except Exception as ex:
        print('Error:', ex)
```

So I'm guessing that there is a problem with the `Content-ID`, but I'm not sure. Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 1):

People have mixed results with Content-ID. Very few people use it these days.

(Base 64 is not widely supported either, for that matter: https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-base64/)

You should host the image on a public server and provide the full URL path to the image in the `src` attribute for it to work, i.e. `<img src="https://www.path.com/to/image/image.jpg" width="100">`